# Angular PrimeNG Calendar - Is there a way to set a minimum end date when using selectionMode="range"?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I would like to use PrimeNG's calendar with **(selectionMode="range")**, but I am having issues figuring out how to set a minimum end date. The "minDate" works fine for the start date, but is there a way to set a minimum end date?

I would like for the minimum end date to be at least 30 days greater than the start date. For example:

If startDate = May 1, 2020
Then an endDate less than 30 days out from the start date should not be selectable(for a total minimum date range of 30 days).

Is this possible or do I just need to make it 2 separate date pickers?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I may be able to use "disabledDates" to do this.  I will just have to build an array of "disabledDates" and pass it dynamically after the start date has been selected.